# Any idea why it shows this error when I try to connect to the server?

Tags: php, mysql

***Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'test'@'192.xx.4.36' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\UI\db.class.php on line 59***

This error was shown when I tried to connect it through php. My details entered are working in oracle sql developer, where I can access the database. One thing to take note is that I entered **192.xx.1.45** (Which is the correct working one) yet the error message gave me another host name.

What could be the error? You might want to see line 59 and 60.. It should be correct..

```
$this->connection = mysqli_connect($this->config->hostname, $this->config->username, $this->config->password);
$this->selectdb = mysqli_select_db($this->connection, $this->config->database);
```

Comment: lol that question gives the exact reason and you are asking for `any idea` ? Your password is incorrect for user `test` or user does not exist

Comment: @Deepu that is not true. It means that the given username/password combination is not valid. It does not mean that you do not have to give password at all

Comment: Is the user in mysql allowed to access from '192.xx.4.36' or just from localhost?

Comment: The error message gives you the exact reason.

Comment: @orangepill I tried it on localhost using "localhost" then "root" and it works, however it didn't work when I switch it to the 192...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your password set in db.class.php on line 59 is wrong.

I suggest you go to C:\xampp\htdocs\UI\db.class.php and scroll down to line 59 and change the mysql settings.

Comment: Man that answer is so much to the point and so much `on the line` :) +1